# Android navigation drawer right side not working

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, illegalargumentexception, drawerlayout

I have a navigation drawer and I try to change its opening position. I want  my navigation drawer to open on the right side.

This is my navigation drawer xml code:

```
<ge.me.custom.CustomDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout5"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#09b52f"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/slidemenumainlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/slidemenuuserimage"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_user_blue" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/slidemenumainlayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/slidemenumainlayout"
            android:divider="#00af25"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my custom drawer:

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {

    public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

And this code is inside the main activity:

```
  mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name) {

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

I wrote a method to open my drawer on the right side but when I run my app, it crashes.

```
public void openDrawer(int gravity) {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(gravity);
}
openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

If I call the method like this:

```
openDrawer(Gravity.START);
```

I do not get an error but the navigation drawer's start position is left.

This is my error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT
```

How can I open the navigation drawer on the right side?

Comment: Have you tried `Gravity.END`?

Comment: I tryed but i have same error @ Noob Coder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `layout_gravity` to `right` in your xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#09b52f"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to a more simple code in the menu's item click. I don't think you need to worry about the drawer being closed or not since you can't reach the icon to tap it when the drawer is opened.

The simple solution would be something like this:

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    } 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks but not working. i don't know what is a wrong